# build octave package from source

Tags: linux, makefile, octave

I want to install [octaviz](http://octaviz.sourceforge.net/) package in octave software.

From the documentation there is stated:

-You'll need octave 2.1.53 or later and VTK CVS to build octaviz. To compile octaviz, run `ccmake .` in the root directory of the source tree, then `make` and finally `make install`.

I first ran `ccmake .`, and it completed successfully after I installed some libs that I was missing.

But, the I ran "make" and it exits with the following errors:

```
>> make
[  1%] Built target vtkWrapOctave
[  1%] Building CXX object Common/CMakeFiles/octaviz.dir/octaviz.o
/home/user12345/octave/octaviz/Common/octaviz.cc:31:24: fatal error: octave/oct.h: No such file or directory
 #include <octave/oct.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [Common/CMakeFiles/octaviz.dir/octaviz.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Common/CMakeFiles/octaviz.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `octave/oct.h` header. This usually means that you don't have Octave installed. If you do have it installed, maybe you are missing the header files and shared libraries (if you are using Linux, did you install octave's -dev or -devel packaqes?) If you have them installed, you must have ran the configure script incorrectly. Either specify the correct options or set the CXX_FLAGS. If you don't know about compiler flags you probably should not change them and instead figure out how to install the octave libraries correctly.

Comment: i do have installed octave, in xubuntu 14.04 using `sudo apt-get install octave`, and it works because i have used octave alone. But didn't install any extra apart from that.

Comment: When i `ccmake .`, i can see some directories declared like **OCTAVIZ_OCT_DIR**, **OCTAVIZ_SHARED_DIR** and the last one for example points to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/3.8.1`  instead of `/usr/share/octave/3.8.1` where i think there are the files needed. But i dont know how i can edit that.

Comment: @AlphaBeta read the answer again. "If you do have [Octave] installed, maybe you are missing the header files and shared libraries (if you are using Linux, did you install octave's -dev or -devel packaqes?)"

Comment: I read it, but still I don't get a clear answer what should I do, rather on what the cause might be. Do you suggest that I should install octave's -dev or -devel packages? Because I haven't installed them, I just installed octave from the debian repository.

Comment: @AlphaBeta I thought it was clear from my answer and then again from my comment. Yes, you also need to install ubuntu's octave dev packages. They contain the header files required to build from source new programs that make use of the octave libraries.

Comment: I uninstalled octave and then I installed it again but building it from the sources this time, following [these](http://wiki.octave.org/User:Rettaw) instructions. But still I get the same error when I try to build octaviz. I don't know if this installed what you say octave dev packages. Could you tell me how to install them, because I can't find anything on the internet about that.

Comment: @AlphaBeta search for octave in the repositories (run `aptitude search octave` on the command line). Aside `octave` itself (which you need to install), there should be something like `liboctave-dev` or `octave-pkg-dev`. Install all of those. Their exact names are dependent on the Ubuntu version.

Comment: I did install all of those you mention, but still the same error occurs. What could it be? I have now octave 4.1.0+ but in my /usr/ directory there are still some files from the octave 3.8.1 version, could it be that it is somehow confused?